# ¿Cómo obtener la suma de numeros impares de la sucuencia de fibonacci javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un programa en JavaScript que suma los numeros impares de la secuencia de Fibonacci, dentro de los 10 primeros números de la secuencia.

El programa me imprime la secuencia correctamente, pero la función a la hora de validar si es par o no, no considera el 21 y 55 como impares, por lo que no los suma en el resultado final.

```
   var fibonacci = [1, 1];
    while (fibonacci.length < 10) {
   fibonacci.push(fibonacci[fibonacci.length - 1] + fibonacci[fibonacci.length - 2]);
   }
    function NumeroImpar(num) {
     for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
     if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
      }
    }
      return num > 1; 
  }
    function SumaFibonacci(fibonacci) {
      let acumulado = 0;
      for (let numero of fibonacci) {
        if (NumeroImpar(numero)) {
          acumulado += numero;
        }
      }
      return acumulado;
    }
    const resultado = SumaFibonacci(fibonacci);
    console.log(`La suma de los números impares en la secuencia de Fibonacci 
    es:${resultado}`);
    console.log("Secuencia de Fibonacci:", fibonacci.toString());
```

Comment: la funcion numero impar (igual a la de tu post anterior!!) no tiene ningun sentido... para que usas el for??? recibis un numero, te fijas si es divisible por 2, y devolves eso... para que queres el for????

Comment: Lo único que necesitas para saber si un número es impar es `x % 2 !== 0`. Para qué usas el bucle? Parece más bien una función para determinar si un número es primo pero mal hecha... yo creo que antes de ponerte a programar es necesario que te detengas un momento a revisar la parte matemática de tu problema. Te sugiero usar una hoja de papel e ir anotando los valores de cada paso de tu código para que realmente veas lo que hace si no eres capaz de verlo directamente sobre código. Ayuda mucho a la hora de entender por qué hay cosas "raras" :)

Comment: Podrias ayudarme a corregir mi error?

Comment: pero.. ya te dijimos cual es tu error... que no entendiste?

Comment: Hola! No necesitas borrar y volver a escribir. Recueeeerda que puedes [edit] todas las veces que haga falta la pregunta, el título, las etiquetas... y con eso no se pierde la historia de las cosas ;)

Comment: Bastaría con: `function NumeroImpar(num) { return num % 2 !== 0; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te han dicho en los comentarios es que tu validación del método NumeroImpar es incorrecta.

```
function NumeroImpar(num) {
     for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
     if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
      }
    }
      return num > 1; 
  }
```

Si le das un número, es comúnmente conocido que sólo necesitas usar la operación [módulo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_m%C3%B3dulo) de tu número contra dos (num mod 2) y ver si el residuo de esa operación es cero o no.

`num modulo 2 !== 0`

Si esta operación módulo es cero (la validación da false), es par. Si no es cero (la validación da true), es impar.

Entonces, como te indican, la cosa es que tienes un ciclo for donde corres i de 2 hasta num y eso se parece sospechosamente a la validación de si es primo o no (mal hecha, no óptima).

Quita el ciclo for y simplemente usa la validación de módulo en un if o equivalente para retornar true o false.

`return num % 2 !== 0;`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @alfabravo , ha sido de mucha ayuda para aclarar mi confusion. Espero puedas seguir aportando con paciencia a mas programadores que iniciamos en este camino

Comment: @LuisGomez Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si esta te ha ayudado a resolver el problema. Saludos!!